# Automatically launch an application if it is not running

Tags: windows-8.1, automation

I have an application which run in background but crashes from time to time.

I am looking for a tool that works in the background and checks if a given application is running and if not it launches it. Maybe some script?

Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use Non Sucking Service Manager ... [NSSM](http://www.nssm.cc/usage)

The first item in [Scenarios](http://www.nssm.cc/scenarios) sounds like a fit ...

*Simply install the service as described in the usage notes. Should your application ever fail or crash, nssm will attempt to start it up again.*

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Process Lasso](https://bitsum.com/processlasso/), I have been using it for a long time already, it does more than relaunch the program when it is stopped.

[image]

Introduction: 
Process Lasso is NOT yet another task manager. It is a process priority optimization and system automation utility. Priority optimization, affinity optimization, core optimization, **automated rules**, automated power profiles; you name it, and Process Lasso does it!